# Configure node_modules from different repo in Gradle configuration (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am looking for changing the reference to `node_modules` to indicate specific path (I am attempting to have android folder at the same level as react native):

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: file("C:/user/john/Separation/rn/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

**settings.gradle**

```
includeBuild 'C:/user/john/Separation/rn/node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin'
apply from: file("C:/user/john/Separation/rn/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: React Native CLI failed to determine Android project configuration. This is likely due to misconfiguration. Config output:
```

I have the folder node_modules under the specified path, but somehow is not recognized.

What would be the way to go to fix this issue?

Thanks